# What is it called when there are two columns in a table that are individually unique?

Tags: sql, database-design, sql-server-2012, key, rdbms

As the question asks I'm wondering what you would call it when a row could be uniquely identified by two separate columns.

I apologize for my lack of formatting, but here goes:

ColumnA: 1,2,3,4,5

ColumnB: A,B,C,D,E

ColumnC: 1,2,1,2,1

ColumnD: A,A,B,B,A

So both Column A and Column B are each individually primary keys? I don't think this is correct, so what would you call this in terms of "keys"?

Comment: An alternate key?  Or perhaps the schema is bad and should be split it into 2 tables.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I am new to this topic in school so thank you for the clarification.

Comment: It's called "breaking 3NF"

Comment: @Bohemian Having two candidate keys does not per se violate any NF.

Comment: @philipxy sure it does: 3NF basically says that rows can be found given the key, the whole key and nothing but the key, but when there are two keys, this is violated either because the key is comprised of multiple parts each of which is unique (doesn't require the whole key) or because either unique key can be used to find a row (can be found without the key).

Comment: @Bohemian That is vague and nevertheless doesn't make sense, eg a (candidate or super) key by definition "can be used to find a row" so your 2nd "because" is always true. Do you realize that your comment says that every table with a one-column PK and one-column UNIQUE NOT NULL is not in 3NF? Even for the example data: The only non-trivial FDs have determinants that are superkeys, so it's in [BCNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form).

Comment: @Bohemian, "A relation R is in third normal form if every non-prime attribute of R is non-transitively dependent on each candidate key of R" (E.F.Codd, 1971, Further Normalization of the Data Base Relational Model) In other words a relation with any number of candidate keys can satisfy 3NF. Verify this for yourself in any good book on the topic or plenty of other places online.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that every row always has a unique A value and every row always has a unique B value then each of them is a "superkey". (Actually, the sets {A} and {B}.)

So the answer is, the table has two one-column superkeys.

But also according to your data no smaller set of columns of either superkey is a superkey, each is also a "candidate key". (The only smaller set is {}, but it's not a superkey given your data.)

So here an equivalent answer is, the table has two one-column candidate keys.

A base table that is like that and that can hold your example data is in 5NF. There is no benefit in decomposing it into other tables.

There is a tradition to pick a candidate key as a "primary key". Then each other one is an "alternate key". But this is not a particularly helpful tradition.

In SQL `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE NOT NULL` actually declares a superkey. You can only have one `PRIMARY KEY` declared per table. SQL does not allow declaring {} as a superkey.